# Have shotwell go through pictures in directory in order?

Tags: fedora, gnome3

This has been bothering me for a long time. I have a fairly default installation of Fedora 16 with Gnome 3. I know that since Fedora 15 (don't know about before) I have never been able to view pictures in order in shotwell.

Steps:

1. Open a folder with a bunch of pictures ordered by name
2. Double click on one of the files, it opens in shotwell
3. Go next, it picks a seemingly random picture instead of the next one by name

Is there any way to be able to have the next feature in Shotwell go to the next picture by name instead of a random one?

In case it matters, this happens on both my ext4 linux partition and on my NTFS windows partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, they fixed it in version 0.12.3. I'm using Fedora 16, and had to compile it from source -- http://yorba.org/shotwell/install.html

Comment: Going through old questions, Fedora 17 fixes this. Thanks!